# How to scale libGDX touches

Tags: android, libgdx, touch, scaling

My touches from my libGDX game are not going to the real-time position I actually press on. I tried the following code:

```html
@Override
    public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
        Vector3 v3 = new Vector3(screenX, screenY, 0);
        gameCamera.unproject(v3);
        screenX = (int) v3.x;
        screenY = (int) v3.y;

        if (startOptionButton.isPressed(screenX, screenY)) {
            startOptionButton.setPressed(true);
        }
        if (startStartButton.isPressed(screenX, screenY)) {
            startStartButton.setPressed(true);
        }
        return false;
    }
```

But this actually doesnt get the real-pressed location. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Not enough code here to see what's wrong. How do you set up and update the camera? Are you remembering to set the camera's projection matrix to the SpriteBatch?

Answer (score 0):

Try to invert `screenY`:

> Vector3 v3 = new Vector3(screenX, -screenY, 0);

I don't know why, but for me it works :]